# Why the conditional operator is not giving the expected result (in Python)?

Tags: python

For the given Python code, can anyone help me to find why I am not getting my expected result?

```
i=1
j="Hello"
k="World"
while i<101:
    if i%15==0: # thanks for answers, this is an extra if which I forgot to remove
        print j+k if i%15==0 else j if i%3==0 else k if i%5==0 else i
    i+=1
```

My expectation:

```
1
2
Hello
4
World
Hello
7
.
14
HelloWorld
.
.
```

But the result is:

```
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
```

Comment: What's the `if` block doing?

Comment: Modulus, print statement only executes if i is divisible by 15.

Comment: You should remove the `if i%15 == 0` block.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't what you submitted as your answer to the FizzBuzz interview question :D

Comment: Chaining three conditional expressions is one or two too many for readability.  Also, replace your while statement with `for i in range(101):` and you will no longer need to increment the loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
if i%15==0:
    print j+k if i%15==0 else j if i%3==0 else k if i%5==0 else i
```

The second line will only execute when `i%15 == 0`, so the first condition on the print will always be true.  That is, every time the second line is executed, `i%15 == 0`, so since you have `j+k if i%15==0` it will always print `j+k`.

If you remove the line `if i%15==0:` then you should get the result that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Because the print statement is within the modulus check, the print statement is only ever reached for multiples of 15.

Within the print statement, if i is divisible by 15, the very first if condition is satisfied.

For those reasons, the only possible value that will be printed is `j+k`, or HelloWorld.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `if i%15==0` the line starting with `print` is only evaluated in those cases where i%15 equals 0. In these cases the first "if" query within the conditional statement is true, which leads to an evaluation of the first "then" case `print j+k` but not of the first "else" case, which is `j if i%3==0 else k if i%5==0 else i`.

Edit: Note that "else" cases are executed only if the "if" query is false - no matter whether further "if" queries within the "else" statement are true or not.